# Display the whole width of a ggplot2 heatmap and improve its appearance as it seems like two plots are united into one after grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, plotly

Hello I have the dataset below:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","small","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

which creates a grouped heatmap with the code:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
g <- melt(Gene_states22, id.vars = c("gene_symbol","panel"))
p1<-ggplot(g, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                        colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black"))+
  facet_wrap(~panel, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x")+
  labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
  theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                             size = 14, 
                             face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                  size = 16, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 25, b = 0, l = 25)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")
p1
ggplotly(p1)%>%
  layout( autosize = F, width = 1450, height = 600,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                     font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                                 size = 9, 
                                                                                 color = "black")))
```

I am facing 2 issues here as you will see:
1) I cannot display the whole width of the plot in one row but the is being broken into 2 rows as you will see.
2) After separating the heatmap in groups( growth,big, small, DF) the plot is displayed strangely as it is like another plot is being stuck on the initial one.

[image]

Comment: To put everything on one row, try `nrow = 1` in `facet_wrap()`.

Comment: I get `Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found` when I print `p1`.

Comment: It does not produce this error to me. p1 is displayed  normally. Thank you for the nrow=1. I t works. I would like to ask if I can place the grey label with the panel types at the bottom instead of displaying it on top.